# Why use Platform Events in standalone native apps?

Tags: apex, isv, asynchronous, executioncontext, platform-event

In Summer '17 Salesforce released [Platform Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro_emp.htm) - a native messaging system accessible via Apex and several APIs.

I assume the main use case for such a feature is to allow integration of Salesforce apps into the SOA of a company meaning connecting Salesforce with other enterprise systems.

But...wouldn't Platform Events also be of great help in many **native and standalone** Salesforce applications? Especially more complex **ISV** applications?

I'm thinking of **Domain Events** as Eric Evans defined them in [his book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321125215) which are [different than Integration Events as described here.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/02/07/domain-events-vs-integration-events-in-domain-driven-design-and-microservices-architectures/)

What's your opinion on this (the most detailed and complete answer will be credited.) Couldn't Platform events also help app developers to:

1. Decouple monolithic, synchronous Apex apps into an architecture of **micro services**. Something similar that OSGI or IOC Containers like Spring do. You can find more details in this question [Implement Domain Event Pattern in Apex - can and should it be done?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108469/)
2. Solve Governor Limit problems by pulling code before and after triggers apart into **separate execution contexts**
3. Build a **communication** channel between Base and Extension Packages **without global** Apex classes.

Replacing tightly-coupled synchronous Apex code which guarantees all-or-nothing consistency with a loosely coupled asynchronous world surely has many drawbacks. If Salesforce.com had those other use cases in mind I would expect them to also provide solutions for that in the next releases.

Comment: Wow I missed that - that could be huge.

Comment: An interesting idea, but is it well suited to a question here? Might be more something suitable for a discussion. You could raise your ideas in the [Platform Events success group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A0000004gjg)

Comment: I wish we had a space for these questions. For one they bring to light important new features we may have missed and two a good intellectual conversation is a welcome diversion from "I need 100% coverage, please help me its urgent". Maybe we need a true Salesforce Fourm with vBulletin. Maybe I will start one up.

Comment: Do you know that it gives separate execution contexts for listeners, and if it's asynchronous or synchronous? It looks like you have asynchronous retry. So are they all asynchronous? Maybe some experiments will help.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I also posted the topic in the group you mentioned.

Comment: @Eric There's always the [developer forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums#!/feedtype=RECENT&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&) if you're feeling masochistic(intending the general use of that adjective).

Comment: One of possible use is described here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54931/how-can-i-cause-side-effects-outside-an-execution-context

Answer (score 2):

This very recent talk by Martin Fowler about [The Many Meanings of Event-Driven Architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STKCRSUsyP0&index=11&list=PLEx5khR4g7PJ94PpgvNx6WohYcGQHY9UJ) contains a lot of wisdom that can help when thinking about how to use this feature in the Salesforce.com ecosystem.

[image: GOTO 2017 • The Many Meanings of Event-Driven Architecture • Martin Fowler]

- A classic use case is to decouple a Salesforce app from other enterprise systems using events (trivial answer)
- Event can also used internally (just look at how Lightning components work together using low-coupled events
- Apex code can use command-style and tell what to do OR make changes a first-class code citizen and model state changes explicitly using events
- Event-based decoupling makes software more flexible but also harder to understand ("What's going on when XYZ happens?") and debug
- Use **Event-Sourcing** to seperate the Application State and a Log of all the Events/Changes that created this state (comparable to Version control)